# True or false propositions about Compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Decide whether the following propositions are true or false. If the claim is valid, supply a short proof, and if the claim is false, provide a counterexample.

(a) The arbitrary intersection of compact sets is compact.

(b) The arbitrary union of compact sets is compact.

(c) Let A be arbitrary and let K be compact, then the intersection $A\bigcap K$ is compact.

(d) If   $F_{1}\supseteq F_{2} \supseteq F_{3} \supseteq F_{4} \cdot\cdot \cdot\cdot $is a nested sequence of nonempty closed sets, then the intersection $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty F_{n}\neq \emptyset$

For (a-c) I would like to have my attempt for these solutions checked. Please let me know if these are accurate, not accurate, or accurate but not sufficient. For (d) I need more assistance.

My attempt:
[image]
[image]

(d) Following the nested interval theorem, this holds. Can someone show me how it does or if I am wrong why it doesn't.

Comment: For C: in $\mathbb R$, is $[1,3]\cap(2,4)$ compact?

Comment: Your reasoning in (a) is wrong. In metric spaces, compact sets are bounded and closed, although the reverse is not true in general. The Heine-Borel Theorem applies only when you're working in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Lets make a small distinction, are you focused on the compact subsets of real numbers or abstract metric spaces?

Answer (score 1):

For c, you are wrong. Take for example the set $A=(\frac{1}{2},1)$ and $K=[0,2]$. Then their intersection is just $A$ which is not compact. As for d), you need a complete metric space, so in the general case it isn't true.

Answer (score 0):

For $(d)$ In complete metric space, it is known as **Cantor's intersection theorem**. [See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem)

For $(c)$ take any open set and a compact set and see there intersection. What they say?

Comment: Oh that's what I was missing. How do (a-c) look?

Comment: $(b)$ looks fine but I have to check $(a)$.

Comment: As @EA304GT indicated, you can only apply that reasoning for $(a)$ if you are working with $\mathbb{R^n}$

Comment: For arbitrary metric space, Heine Borel theorem: A subset of a metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded.